# When i change fancyput to thisfancyput it dissapears in pdf

Tags: fancyhdr

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,top=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize Sida \thepage\ av \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{1.5em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\cornersize{.3}

{\huge Business}

\thisfancyput*(230pt,-22pt){\ovalbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{215pt}
      \huge Faktura
    \end{minipage}}}

\fancyput*(230pt,-82pt){\ovalbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{87pt}
      \textbf{Fakturanummer:}\\1234
    \end{minipage}}}

\fancyput*(358pt,-82pt){\ovalbox{%
    \begin{minipage}{87pt}
      \textbf{Fakturadatum:}\\2012-12-12
    \end{minipage}}}


\end{document}
```

When I change  any of the \fancyput to \thisfancyput it just disappears. I want to do this because I do not want to reapeat the boxes on the next page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is not complete (missing \documentclass) and doesn't show your problem, as it doesn't contain a \thisfancyput. Always make a example that we can really use for a test.

Comment: Sorry was  a bad copy.  Added the documentclass and one of three boxes are now using \thisfancyput and just disappears.

Comment: It looks as if you can have only one `\thisfancyput` on a page, and not combine it with other `\fancyput` or other `\thisfancyput`.  I would use eso-pic and tikz for this instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I tried to understand what you want to achieve.

Conceptually speaking I think your solution is not very elegant.

For code with better structure and which is easier to customize i suggest a solution based on the `tcolorbox` package.

The following example also leverages the `raster` and `skins` library that comes with `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster, skins}

\fancyhf{} 
\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize Sida \thepage\ av \pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, top=0em, noparskip, raster valign=top, raster force size=false]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[blankest, fontupper=\huge]
        Business
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcboxeditemize}[raster columns=2, raster equal height]{blankest}
           \tcbitem[raster multicolumn=2] Faktura 
           \tcbitem \textbf{Fakturanummer:}\\1234
           \tcbitem \textbf{Fakturadatum:}\\2012-12-12
    \end{tcboxeditemize}
\end{tcbraster} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I wanted! :)